# backbone add files to collection takes several seconds

Tags: backbone.js, cordova

I have a collection I fill with elements of an existing array. A view is listening to the collections add event. It renders each time I add something to the collection.

```
 collection.add(_collection);  //_collection = array of model objects
                               // collection = backbone collection
```

This is the rendering and initializing of my view:

```
initialize: function(options){
        this.el = options.el;
        fbsCollection.update(this.attributes.folder);
        this.collection = fbsCollection.collection;
        this.collection.on("add", this.render, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        localStorage.state

        localStorage.state = 2;
        if(fbsCollection.folder.get("folder")!="")
            document.getElementById('preFolderButton').style.display = 'block';
        else
            document.getElementById('preFolderButton').style.display = 'none';
        this.$el.empty();
        var temp = _.template(aftemp, {boxFolder: this.collection, folder : fbsCollection.folder});
        this.$el.html(temp);
        created = true;
        $("#boxBrowserContent").trigger("create");
    },
```

The array contains 20 elements. Until the last element is added to the backbone.collection 10 seconds past.

I updated from phonegap 3.0.0 to 3.3.0 recently. That took some bad effects and I fear this is something that has to do with the update as well.

Comment: Have you tried running this/similar code outside of phonegap to make sure it's a backbone problem?

Comment: No, but this is a great idea. I'll check that :)

Comment: I use the same code on phonegap-3.0.0 and it works fine. I guess there's an issue between phonegap3.3.0 and backbone manipulating the dom.